# How can I load a source file into Haskell (ghci)?

Tags: macos, haskell, ghci

I have created a file in text edit on mac called: `1stfunctionite.hs` with the function:

```
doubleX x = x + x
```

Then saved it to my documents. I then went onto terminal called `ghci` and entered

```
:l 1stfunctionite
```

Into the prelude, however, an error message came up of:

```
target ‘1stfunctionite is not a module name or a source file
```

How can I create a source file with this function inside so i can use it within terminal in prelude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be in the same directory for it to work, just do `:cd <your directory>` in ghci and you will be fine.

Comment: How do I know which directory I'm in when using prelude as I can't type pwd in prelude. Please could you give me the terminal code to move the file "1stfunctionite" to the correct directory to make this work.

Comment: @repaj In ghci type ``:cd My\ Documents`` (or whatever your escape character is) to change the cwd to ``My Documents``.

Comment: I used :cd ~/Documents and used "show paths" to give"
current working directory: 
  /Users/Jasper/Document"

Comment: but it still didn't work after that even if the file was in the directory documents

Comment: @repaj Try navigating to the directory and then starting ghci

Comment: i read a guide which said the file must be in the same folder from which ghci was invoked - do you know which folder this is?I have a folder haskell - is this it - or do I have to navigate even further within this folder - or is it somewhere else?

Comment: @repaj it does not matter which folder

Comment: @repaj I doubt that, TextEdit is a regular text editor

Comment: Ok - do you recommend doing anything - ive renamed it to main and then <command line>:
    Could not find module ‘Main’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
 came up

Comment: I figured it out - i created a folder then i created a process cat < Haq.hs and added some code inside this process then ran it within ghci and it worked!

Comment: @repaj have fun coding :)

Comment: Module names can't begin with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to `cd` into the directory containing your files before running `ghci`.